# How to enable UOM conversion tab

Tags: openbravo

I am trying to setup UOM conversion for SKUs. Like to know how do we enable UOM conversion tab. can anyone pl help me on this.

regards,
usman

Comment: I have noticed that it has not been set 'Active' by default.I think this is to be done in Preferences? can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Set yourself to the **System Administrator** role.
2. Open the window: **Application** || **Application Dictionary** || **[Windows, Tabs, and Fields](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ManualDoc%3aCommon_OBConcepts&Processes#Advanced_Features)**
3. Search for and select the module name **Unit of Measure**
4. In the tab named **Tab** open the line with the name **Conversion** and set it to active.

Comment: Did it work for you? If so, please accept my answer.